# Concatenate #define after expanding

Tags: c

Lets say I have some #defines

```
#define _TEST_FOO()  // some code here
#define _TEST_BAR()  // some code here

#define ABC FOO
#define BCD BAR
```

Can I create another #define like so:

```
#define CONCATENATE(x)   //??something here??
```

Where if somewhere in code I would use`CONCATENATE(ABC);` or `CONCATENATE(BCD);` it would generate `_TEST_FOO();` and `_TEST_BAR();` respectively.

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry for the mistake, I meant:

```
#define _TEST_FOO_CLK_ENABLE()
#define _TEST_BAR_CLK_ENABLE()
```

So the result when calling `CONCATENATE(x);` should be:

```
_TEST_FOO_CLK_ENABLE();
_TEST_BAR_CLK_ENABLE();
```

Comment: See also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible with one extra round of expansion:

```
#define CONCATENATE(x) CONCATENATE2(x)
#define CONCATENATE2(x) _TEST_ ## x ## _CLK_ENABLE ()
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3605299b273838c2)

The extra indirection is necessary to force the argument itself (e.g. `ABC`) to be expanded. Without it, we'd end up with `_TEST_ABC()`.

Comment: @user1806687 Are there any more edits you are going to do to the question? I am not updating the answer to hit a moving target. Please tag me when the question is in its final form so I can address it (and please *please*, in the future, try to get the question right the first time).

Comment: @user1806687 OK, edited.

Comment: I will accept your anwser as it was the solution for the problem as I asked. But it did not work with my case, I ommited a lot of information. If you want to have another go at it, new question is posted at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600682/how-to-force-macro-to-not-expand